# How to simplify processing values from Map

Tags: java, hashmap

I often have to write constructs like: if the key is there, get the value and do something, otherwise put a new value (sometimes with additional processing)Is there any way to simplify this code?

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
  
    if (map.containsKey("someKey")) {
      //  get the value and do something          
        map.merge("someKey", 3, Integer::sum);
    } else {
         map.put("someKey", 0);
    }
```

Comment: It depends on what is "get the value and do something". For your example, you can just replace the if else to `map.merge("someKey", 0, (x, y) -> x + y + 3);`

Answer (score 0):

In certain situations, you can end up compressing the code and making it harder to read. Depends on the overall picture.

It seems you're planning to start with an empty Map, aiming for a single iteration, then what you have is great.

Pardon my playful response here:

Option 1: Neutral Lawful
You have the option of using a ternary operator instead of an if-else statement.

Option 2: Chaotic Lawful
Use a list stream and play around with the stream terminal operation 'foreach' if you'd like. Heck use a ternary operator on your lambda if you fancy some more functional madness too.

Option 3: Neutral Evil
If the map already had all keys initialized with a value of 0, you could essentially just merge all entry keys. Given I don't have full context I can't say iterating more than once is a good idea if it's not necessary.